# Xcode, play each sound for each view

Tags: xcode, image, audio, view

I am new to Xcode and programming.  I am designing a toddler app that has multiple images, one image for each view.  When the screen is tapped, one sound should play.  After swiping to the next page, there is another view with a different image.  When this new image is tapped, a new sound is played.
What is the best way to implement AVfoundation kit so that it plays one sound for each image?

Thanks in advance.

Doan

Comment: SO is not a place for getting people program your code for you, sorry!

Comment: In response to jtheman: OK.  I won't ask for the code; I have edited my question. I already know how to implement swipe and images.  I am asking for the best way to implement the audio so that it plays for each image.  I was able to implement audio for the first image but it's the same audio for the second image.

Answer (score 0):

Look into UIViews, and especially how to get te current view. All the nessecary information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.htm). If the user switches from view, then the sound should be switched to. You could accomplish this by implementing a method which checks if the view has switched. Then, if that happened, you can switch the value of a sound ivar to a different value.